# Why is lua on host system slower than in the linux vm?

Tags: c, linux, macos, lua, clang

Comparing executing time of [this Lua Script](https://github.com/markuman/sumdata/blob/master/script-lang/sumdata.lua) on a Macbook Air (Mac OS 10.9.4, i5-4250U (1.3GHz), 8GB RAM) to a VM (virtualbox) running Arch Linux.

### Compiling Lua 5.2.3 in a Arch Linux virtualbox

First I've compiled lua by myself using clang, to compare it with the Mac OS X clang binary.

#### using tcc, gcc and clang

```
$ tcc *[^ca].c lgc.c lfunc.c lua.c -lm -o luatcc
$ gcc -O3 *[^ca].c lgc.c lfunc.c lua.c -lm -o luagcc
/tmp/ccxAEYH8.o: In function `os_tmpname':
loslib.c:(.text+0x29c): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
$ clang -O3 *[^ca].c lgc.c lfunc.c lua.c -lm -o luaclang
/tmp/loslib-bd4ef4.o:loslib.c:function os_tmpname: warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
```

clang version in VM

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

#### compare the file size

```
$ ls -lh |grep lua
-rwxr-xr-x 1 markus markus 210K 20. Aug 18:21 luaclang
-rwxr-xr-x 1 markus markus 251K 20. Aug 18:22 luagcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 markus markus 287K 20. Aug 18:22 luatcc
```

### VM benchmarking

#### clang binary ~3.1 sec

```
$ time ./luaclang sumdata.lua data.log
Original Size: 117261680 kb
Compressed Size: 96727557 kb
real    0m3.124s
user    0m3.100s
sys  0m0.020s
```

#### gcc binary ~3.09 sec

```
$ time ./luagcc sumdata.lua data.log
Original Size: 117261680 kb
Compressed Size: 96727557 kb
real    0m3.090s
user    0m3.080s
sys 0m0.007s
```

#### tcc binary ~7.0 sec - no surprise here :)

```
$ time ./luatcc sumdata.lua data.log
Original Size: 117261680 kb
Compressed Size: 96727557 kb
real    0m7.071s
user    0m7.053s
sys 0m0.010s
```

### Compiling on Mac OS X

Now compiling lua with the same clang command/options like in the VM.

```
$ clang -O3 *[^ca].c lgc.c lfunc.c lua.c -lm -o luaclangmac
loslib.c:108:3: warning: 'tmpnam' is deprecated: This function is provided for
compatibility reasons only. Due to security concerns inherent in the design of tmpnam(3),
it is highly recommended that you use mkstemp(3)
instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
lua_tmpnam(buff, err);
^
loslib.c:57:33: note: expanded from macro 'lua_tmpnam'
#define lua_tmpnam(b,e) { e = (tmpnam(b) == NULL); }
^
/usr/include/stdio.h:274:7: note: 'tmpnam' declared here
char *tmpnam(char *);
^
1 warning generated.
```

clang version Mac OS X

I've tried two version. 3.4.2 and the one which is provided by xcode. The version 3.4.2 is a bit slower.

```
Markuss-MacBook-Air:bin markus$ ./clang --version
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-rc1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
Markuss-MacBook-Air:bin markus$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

#### file size

```
$ ls -lh|grep lua
-rwxr-xr-x 1 markus staff 194K 20 Aug 18:26 luaclangmac
```

### HOST benchmarking

#### clang binary ~4.3 sec

```
$ time ./luaclangmac sumdata.lua data.log
Original Size: 117261680 kb
Compressed Size: 96727557 kb
real    0m4.338s
user    0m4.264s
sys 0m0.062s
```

## Why?

I would have expected that the host system is a little faster than the virtualization (or roughly the same speed). But not that the host system is reproducible slower.

So, any ideas or explanations?

## Update 2014.10.30

Meanwhile I've installed Arch Linux nativly on my MBA. The benchmarks are as fast as in the Arch Linux VM.

Comment: I would argue that unless both host and guest are using the same OS it does not make much sense to compare the performance. Have you tried your benchmark on the bare metal with a Linux Live CD?

Comment: one possible reason is that linux uses most of the unallocated system memory for a disk cache.

Comment: I think that when a script is nearly completely file I/O, the real question might be "Why is linux' file I/O faster that OSX in this particular case?".

Comment: @cubuspl42, indeed, this is interesting.
Old hfs+ on host system vs. guest system using btrfs powered by Intel direct I/O (VT-d) virtualization technology.

Comment: It has to be caching. Have you tried turning that off for the disk device? If the guest is able to cache and carry on, then it is not delayed whilst the host at some point is scheduled to flush the cache. For the host only case, it is harder to say, and depends how the host disk is configured and again if caching, or if the host is doing sync i/o accesses. You also probably want to play with virtio vs ide disks. virtio is generally faster too than ide access. hth

Comment: Could you do the same thing for a script which is more computationally intensive? I suspect the IO operations are the bulk of the processing; Linux may do it faster.

Comment: you've got a different libc in the two environments maybe that's significant

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to run 'perf stat' instead of 'time'. It provides you much more details and the time measurement is more correct, avoiding timing differences inside the VM.

Here is an example:

```
$ perf stat ls > /dev/null
```

Performance counter stats for 'ls':

```
     23.348076      task-clock (msec)         #    0.989 CPUs utilized          
             2      context-switches          #    0.086 K/sec                  
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            93      page-faults               #    0.004 M/sec                  
    74,628,308      cycles                    #    3.196 GHz                     [65.75%]
       740,755      stalled-cycles-frontend   #    0.99% frontend cycles idle    [48.66%]
    29,200,738      stalled-cycles-backend    #   39.13% backend  cycles idle    [60.02%]
    80,592,001      instructions              #    1.08  insns per cycle        
                                              #    0.36  stalled cycles per insn
    17,746,633      branches                  #  760.090 M/sec                   [60.00%]
       642,360      branch-misses             #    3.62% of all branches         [48.64%]

   0.023609439 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the HFS+ journaling feature is adding latency.  This would be easy enough to test: If TimeMachine is running on the Macbook Air, you could try disabling it, and disable journaling on the filesystem (obviously you should back up first).  As root:

```
diskutil disableJournal YourDiskVolume
```

I'd see if that's the cause of the problem.  Then i would immediately re-enable journaling.

```
diskutil enableJournal YourDiskVolume
```

OS X 10.9.2 had a journaling-related bug that would hang the filesystem... [this page](http://macperformanceguide.com/blog/2014/20140331_1-OSX-Mavericks-hang-bug.html) explores this bug further, and even though the bug (#15821723) hasn't been reported as fixed, journaling reportedly no longer crashes the disk controller.

Answer (score 0):

to test the speed of lua, instead of reading a file hard-code some sample data into the test script and loop over the lines over and over as necessary.  Like others mentioned, the filesystem effects are going to outweigh any compiler differences.